# Center <video> tag in responsive web page

Tags: html, css

I would like to learn how to CSS a `<video>` such that when resizing a webpage, the video's dimensions are unchanged but appears centered like the CSS `background-position: center` but for CSS.

Here's pseudo code,

```
...

<style>
    video { video-position: center } /* I wish */
</style>

...

<div id="background">
    <video autoplay>
        <source src="background.mp4">
    </vido>
</div>

...
```

The CSS equivalent of `video { video-position: center }` as if `background-position` is what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: You want a responsive video embed but the height remains unchanged? That doesn't sound right. See embedresponsively.com for a standard implementation of embedding responsively.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the clarification. I mean for the video to maintain its dimensions and appear centered as the webpage is resized. So the webpage changes dimensions but the video is centered in the background much like the CSS `background-position: center`

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the intended experience. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 2):

Give the `#background` div a position of relative and then a padding-bottom of a percentage.  Mess with the padding bottom percentage until you get your desired height.  Then give the video tag a position of absolute and width and height of 100% like so:

Here is a fiddle [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/cf92mjmq/)

```
#background{
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:55%;
}
#background video{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
video {
    width: 720px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Little different. The intention is to have the video's dimensions unchanged when the webpage is resized, but if the webpage's width is resized, the video appears centered in the background rather than the left portion remaining on the screen and the right invisible.

Comment: what are the dimensions do you want it to stay?

Comment: For example, `width: 720px; height: auto`

Comment: That's close. The last bit is when the window width is less than `720px`, the video is centered in the background rather than hugging the left edge of the window. I want resizing the window's width less than `720px` to hide equal `px` from the left and right of the video, not just right.